# how to automatically align long text in next line in TextView under CardView

Tags: java, android, textview, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am using a `TextView` under **android.support.v7.widget.CardView**. However, whenever I try to set a long text, `TextView` is not giving the full result.

```
 List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();
    userList.add(new User(R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
            "Amit", "9988776655",
            "amit@sonevalley.comamit@sonevalley.comamit@sonevalley.comamit@sonevalley.comamit@sonevalley.comamit@sonevalley.com"));
```

This is my java code(as an example) and this shows in the app like this:
[for this first one 'Amit'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNvo6.png).

How to solve this? If the text is long then it will automatically set it to next line.

Here is my full `Cardview.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="16dp">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cvSingleUser"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="12dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivProfilePic"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvProfileName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivProfilePic" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPhoneNumber"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/tvProfileName"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivProfilePic" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvEmailId"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/tvPhoneNumber"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivProfilePic" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

and this is the snapshot of the java code:[Java Snap Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b93bP.jpg)

this is the java full code

```
public class AllUsersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AllUsersAdapter.UserViewHolder>{

private List<MainActivity.User> userList;
private Context context;
public AllUsersAdapter(List<MainActivity.User> userList, Context context) {
    this.userList = userList;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public UserViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.single_cardview_layout, null);
    UserViewHolder userViewHolder = new UserViewHolder(view);
    return userViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(UserViewHolder holder, int position) {
    MainActivity.User user = userList.get(position);

    String a=user.getEmailId().toString();
    holder.tvProfileName.setText(user.getProfileName());
    holder.tvPhoneNumber.setText(user.getPhoneNumber());
    holder.tvEmailId.setText(a);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return userList.size();
}

public static class UserViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


    TextView tvProfileName;
    TextView tvPhoneNumber;
    TextView tvEmailId;
    public UserViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tvProfileName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvProfileName);
        tvPhoneNumber = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPhoneNumber);
        tvEmailId = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvEmailId);

    }
}
```

}

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
yourTextView.append("\n anotherTextPart")
```

Comment: this text will be dynamically added. i set here just to see the result

Answer (score 0):

First of all - if your string will not have white spaces TextView will not able to properly arange text in multi line.

Try to set following attributes :

```
<TextView
 ...
 android:maxLines="4"/>
```

**Update** here is my test that works even without flag above:

MainActivity.java:

```
private class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView email;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        email = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvEmailId);
    }
}

private class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View card = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.user_card, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(card);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.email.setText("test@gmail.comtest@gmail.comtest@gmail.comtest@gmail.comtest@gmail.comtest@gmail.comtest@gmail.comtest@gmail.com");
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 5;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    .....
    RecyclerView view = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

    view.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

    view.setAdapter(new Adapter());
}
```

user_card.xml (changed `layout_height` to `wrap_content`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cvSingleUser"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="12dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivProfilePic"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:src="@drawable/user"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvProfileName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:text="test test test"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivProfilePic" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvPhoneNumber"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="test"
                android:layout_below="@id/tvProfileName"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivProfilePic" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvEmailId"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:text="test@gmail.comtest@gmail.comtest@gmail.comvtest@gmail.com"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/tvPhoneNumber"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivProfilePic" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

main_activity :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I tried this.but it only adding whitespace not aligning the string in new line

Comment: I've tried your code and it working for one cardview. Maybe problem during inflating. how do you inflate your cards on layout?

Comment: Just using RecycleView.can you please share your code.

Comment: No sir, when i am using android:text="vasckhvacnv.acv.ahjscv.asjhcvajhvjahxvjahcvascjhvacjhvcasj"this in my xml it is working fine but the problem is when i set the text from java class. this is still not working.

Comment: I've apdated code - and it's working anyway. what version of cardview support lib are you using? And also which target, compile versions?

Comment: compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+' and target vertion 23

Comment: I've tried with your libs and it working also. In your code could you use `.inflate(R.layout.single_cardview_layout, parent, null);`

Comment: no sir it is not working.i just update my code with yours
   `@ Override
    public UserViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View card = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_cardview_layout, parent, false);

        //View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.single_cardview_layout, null);
        UserViewHolder userViewHolder = new UserViewHolder(card);
        return userViewHolder;
    }`

Comment: That's really strange. Unfortunately I runed out of ideas what could be wrong.

Comment: I think problem was width.solved by using specific width.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using

> TableLayout

and using specific width.full code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:padding="16dp">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cvSingleUser"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TableLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="270dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvProfileName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:text="test test test"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPhoneNumber"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:text="test"
            android:layout_below="@id/tvProfileName" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvEmailId"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="test@gmail.comtest@gmail.comtest@gmail.comvtest@gmail.comtest@gmail.comtest@gmail.comtest@gmail.comvtest@gmail.comtest@gmail.comtest@gmail.comtest@gmail.comvtest@gmail.comtest@gmail.comtest@gmail.comtest@gmail.comvtest@gmail.com"
            android:layout_below="@id/tvPhoneNumber" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```